# Why is my ajax not performing my sql query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I've been trying to find out why my ajax call and sql query is not working.. As I looked into my script, I can't find anything wrong, my request page looks like this :

```
echo  '<html><body>
        <div class="first-row" bordercolor="yellow">
        <div id="countdown"></div>
        <script>
        function UpdateRecord()
      {
        var userid = '.$userid.';
          $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"spotlightcount.php",
                data:{ userid: userid },
                success:function () {
                    alert("Ok!");
                }

            });
     }
        </script>
        <script>
        var timeleft = 10;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
      timeleft -= 1;
      if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
        UpdateRecord();
      }
    }, 1000);
        </script>
        </div>
    <div class="second-row">
      <iframe src="'.$row['adurl'].'"></iframe>
    </div>
    </body></html>';
```

And then spotlightcount.php has this :

```
include "config.php";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Error: Unable to select database");
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['userid'])){

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

@mysql_query("Update ".$prefix."members set  responsepoints=responsepoints+10, credits=credits+10 where Id=$userid limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
}


exit;

?>
```

Now whatever I do, when I load the page, finish the 10 second countdown, the stats still doesn't update.. I can't find what's wrong about it.

Comment: There's a variety of debugging to be done here.  Start with the page loaded in your browser.  Open your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors on the development console?  On the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  If no AJAX request is made, place debugging breakpoints in your JavaScript code and reload the page to observe what it's doing.  If the AJAX request is made and looks right, time to debug the server-side code.  What is the actual SQL query being executed?  What is the result of that query?  Check for MySQL errors.

Comment: Your PHP isn't returning anything via echo.

Comment: @Dave tested it locally. Seems fine.

Comment: You should check your mysql connection & query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jQuery functions (`$.ajax`), but you haven't imported the library.

Add before closing body tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Useful tip: Use DevTools (F12) in order to debug your front-end code. You would see the following exception in console tab: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Use network tab to see your Ajax request.